# Eclipse/CDT Pretty Printing With Remote Debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, cross-compiling, pretty-print, gdbserver

I'm trying to add pretty printing for STL objects in my Eclipse/CDT (Mars release) to remote debug application running in an ARM board.

I can succesfully debug my application using Eclipse and gdbserver. For this purpose I use the following gdbinit file:

```
set sysroot remote:/
```

Then I'm trying to follow the steps available in teh Eclipse Wiki to have the pretty printing for STL structures:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ

I downloaded successfully the files from SVN, and added the indicated lines to my gdbinit file, which became:

```
set sysroot remote:/    
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/rvcpu/prettyprinting')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

When I start the Debug session I get the following error on the gdb trace:

```
418,226 12-gdb-set target-wide-charset UTF-32
418,227 12^done
418,227 (gdb) 
418,228 13-gdb-set dprintf-style call
418,228 13^done
418,228 (gdb) 
418,232 14source /home/rvcpu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/gdbinit
418,232 &"source /home/rvcpu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/gdbinit\n"
418,232 =cmd-param-changed,param="sysroot",value="remote:/"
```

I believe I must indicate to GDB, somehow, that the python script is located on my host computer, not the target. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks,
Bernardo

Answer (score 0):

You should add that lines to .gdbinit on host machine and python directory with "libstdcxx" library should be on host machine too.
And if you have python directory in subdirectory "prettyprinting", you should set that directory which contain libstdcxx directory.
So if you has printers here:

```
/home/rvcpu/prettyprinting/python/libstdcxx/v6/
```

you need to insert

```
/home/rvcpu/prettyprinting/python/
```

to your sys.path in python code of .gdbinit.